# Object Reference Handling in C#

Tags: c#

I was working on a c# program today and ended up having to chase a bug for quite some time.

I was trying to make a copy of an object change a few fields and send it on as well as the original

for example

```
Function(Object A)
{
    Object B = new Object();
    Object B = A;

    B.foo = "bar";

    Send(A);

    Send(B);
}
```

My program started treating A and B as the same object meaning that any changes to A would also change B and vise versa.

I know that the Object A and B are both referencing the same memory.

Is there a short hand way to ensure the line `Object B = A` references new memory thus creating different objects. Or is the only way to create a copy constructor in my Object and create B with `Object B = new Object(A)`

eg:

```
Object(Object a){
   foo = a.foo;
   ...
}
```

Basically i just what to know more about how C# handles object references and memory allocations. Big subject i know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx. You probably want to use a `struct` if you want a (shallow) copy on assignment.

Comment: FYI, `Object B = new Object();` does nothing for you, since the next line, you set `B` to something else.

Comment: ... because against all appearance, "Object B" does not create an Object, object or "object". It doesn't even declare a variable holding one.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the protected `MemberwiseClone` method, which will make a shallow copy of all the object. If you can modify the class of the object, you can even create a public `Clone` method that delegates to this. And if you're willing to use structs instead of classes, any assignment will create a copy. This is because structs are value types, and assigning one value type variable to another creates a copy.

With regard to `MemberwiseClone`, note the part where I said "shallow." Value type fields will be copied, but reference type fields will still refer to the same underlying objects.

Comment: You might want to say _why_ a struct assignment will create a copy.

Comment: Was the reason you were going for that structs are value types, and all value types are copied when assigned, or something else?

Comment: _is_ there something else? I meant value types.

Comment: just wasn't sure what you were thinking, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is serialization. You serialize original object and deserialize in another object. C# support the approach widely.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 objects present in your code.  There is the one passed in via the parameter `A`, and the one instantiated on line 3.  The second one is discarded immediately when you assign to `B`.  `B` now holds a reference to the same object that variable `A` references.  When you update its `foo` property through the `B` reference, this change is visible when you access it via the `A` reference.

If you want `B` to refer to a copy of what is in `A`, you can either define and use a copy constructor (`B = new SomeClass(A)`) or define and use a Clone function (`B = A.Clone()`).  After either of these operations, `A` and `B` will refer to different object instances.  There are also solutions involving structs ("value types") but that's generally not what a beginner is looking to do.  Outside of that, just remember that `B = A` doesn't create a new object.